# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

estoy tratando de mostrar los registros de una base de datos a una tabla, el cual tengo al conexión PDO, el problema que me salta un error  que espera un parámetro, ya verifique la tabla de la base de datos y esta correcto, en código de PHP que tengo donde realizo la sentencia no se si me falte algún detalle que implementar o realizar el código PHP fuera del HTML, o también la sentencia preparada puede que este mal, si alguien me podría orientar donde esta mi error ya que no he podido resolver este pequeño detalle.

**Warning**

`Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in`

**conexion.php**

```
  <?php

   try{
 $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dpw2; charset=utf8','root','');

//echo 'Conexión exitosa';
 } catch (PDOException $e) {

 die("¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage());     
}
?>
```

**Lista de registros**

```
<?php

 include("conexion.php");

 $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM  inventario");
  $consulta->execute();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Tech center</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
 </head>

 <body>
 <header class="encabezado">
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="regresar">
            <a href="administrador.php"><img src="image/back_arrow.png" />Regresar</a>
        </div>
     </div>
   </header>

  <main>
    <div class="lista">
        <h1>Lista de productos</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="tabla">
        <section id="tabla">
            <table class="table  table-fixed">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="width: 1330px">
                        <th style="width: 30px">ID</th>
                        <th style="width: 100px">Nombre</th>
                        <th style="width: 110px">Descripción</th>
                        <th style="width: 110px">Costo</th>
                        <th style="width: 180px">Precio</th>
                        <th style="width: 120px">Existencia</th>
                        <th style="width: 180px" colspan="2">Operaciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <?php while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){ ?>
                    <tr style="width: 1330px">
                        <td style="width: 100px"><?php echo $row['ID_producto']; ?></td>
                        <td style="width: 110px"><?php echo $row['Nombre_producto']; ?></td>
                        <td style="width: 110px"><?php echo $row['Descripcion']; ?></td>
                        <td style="width: 180px"><?php echo $row['Costo']; ?></td>
                        <td style="width: 120px"><?php echo $row['Precio']; ?></td>
                        <td style="width: 240px"><?php echo $row['Existencia']; ?></td>
                        <td style="width: 80px"><a href="">Modificar</a></td>
                        <td style="width: 80px"><a href="">Eliminar</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
          
          }
          ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </section>

        </div>
     </main>


  </body>
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código de `conexion.php`, parece ser que ahí está el origen del error.

Comment: @Triby ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Por qué mezclas el uso de la mysqli con PDO?, considero que para evitar no solo este error sino futuros continues con PDO que ya existe en tu conexión y hagas los cambios necesarios

Comment: @BetaM tiene la razón  y ya corregí el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo corregí de esta manera.

Implementado el uso de `(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Quedando de esta forma `while($row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que la *mezcla* que haces al implementar la conexión con PDO pero posterior querer obtener e iterar los posibles resultados por medio de MySQLi es lo que hace que el código falle en primer lugar.

Ahora cuando tratas de iterar a: **`$consulta`** si antes haces un `var_dump()` de la misma verás que contiene algo como lo siguiente:

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(19) "SELECT * FROM inventario"
}
```

Y de ahi el fallo que estés pasando como argumento un objeto al método [*mysqli_fetch_assoc* de MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Una posible solución es que uses el método [*`fetchAll()`*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) para obtener una matriz de datos de esta forma:

```
$filasInventario = $consulta->fetchAll();
```

Ahora si evalúas el contenido de esta última variable verás como contiene todas las filas recuperadas de tu tabla.

Ahora con un ciclo foreach podrás acceder a todos los recursos por medio de la clave asignada en cada array

```
foreach($filasInventario as $filaResultados) {
    echo $filaResultados["clave1"];
    ................
    echo $filaResultados["claveN"];
}
```